# How to set focus for AutoCompleteText View if value entered is wrong

Tags: java, android

```
setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (currentfocus==false)
            {
                if (!v.hasFocus())
                {   
                    currentfocus=true;
                    v.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
            }
                if(currentfocus==true)
                {
                    if(v.hasFocus())
                    {
                        v.clearFocus();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Not sure about this particular issue, but as an aside, you should write 'if (currentfocus == false)' as 'if (!currentfocus)' and without the ! for true comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens with your code?

On focus changed, you ask that the view requests focus if it does not have it, and requests that the view clear focus if it does have it.

If these requests are asynchronous, then onFocusChange will keep getting called over and over as focus goes from your view to something else to your view again.

If the requests are processed as they are given, you will loop infinitely and probably get a stack overflow.

Comment: the problem with code is it will set the focus to next child view(autotextcomplete in my case) for which control moves and even to the requested view... so now there will two having focus...

Comment: problem got fixed. Actually focus listener was getting called twice, for one view which comes out of focus and for the the view which get focus.. so it as per my above logic both are getting focus. problem soved by keeping ids both views and setting focus as required.

Answer (score 0):

keep your widgets ids with you while requesting focus for any widgets.you need both ids widget which leaving focus and widget which is gaining. Then use onFocusChangeListener appropriately. 
keep in mind that on change focus listener called twice both the widgets, widget which is loosing focus and the widget which is gaining it.